# Matlab does not replace symbolic function by its expression

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have three symbolic functions : sigma_r, sigma_theta and sigma_z. My three functions are expressed as function of two other symbolic functions : epsilon_r, epsilon_theta. For example

```
sigma_r = 125021*epsilon_r + 132154*epsilon_theta
```

Moreover epsilon_r, epsilon_theta are function of another symbolic function which is u(r) For example

```
epsilon_r = diff(u)
```

I would like to solve the following differential equation :

```
diff(sigma_r)+(sigma_r-sigma_theta)/r+rho*w^2*r==0
```

Actually this differential equation can be expressed as a differential equation of u(r).

I ask Matlab to substitute in the expression of sigma_r (and sigma_theta) all the variable so that sigma_r (and sigma_theta) are expressed only as function of u.

Matlab did well but when it solves the differential equation it doesn't replace sigma_theta as an expression of u. He replaces only sigma_r.

Here are the commands:

```
sigma_r = subs(sigma_r)
sigma_theta = subs(sigma_theta)
u(r) = dsolve(diff(sigma_r)+(sigma_r-sigma_theta)/r+rho*w^2*r==0)
```

It solves and returns:

```
u(r) =
(r*sigma_theta - (r^3*rho*w^2)/3)/r + C5/r
```

You can see that sigma_theta is still dependent of u.

Can you please help me telling to matlab to replace sigma_theta by it expression in u and to solve the differential equation.

Comment: Please shorten this question to focus on what the question is – show your actual full/runnable code, describe the expected output, and what you actually get. I don't "see that `sigma_theta` is still dependent on `u`". It appears to be a simple symbolic variable rather than a symbolic function (`symfun`).

Comment: Dear horchler,
Thank you for your answer. In fact you help me a lot by telling me that i should declare sigma_theta as symbolic function rather than a symbolic variable. I modify my code and it works. Thank you.